# How to get the Data from the Slick grid after update the Slick grid table?

Tags: json, slickgrid

In our Application ,After editing the Slick grid table ,I want to update .For update I have to convert the Slick grid data into Json string and pass the string to the controller.
How can get the Entire slick grid data ?
For displaying the slick grid information ,I am getting  a json string ,from the json string i am displaying the datas in the slick grid.Now after edit/change i want the entire grid data .How can i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DataView it will be different, but if you're not then you can simply do this:

```
var data = grid.getData();
```

Comment: Hi idbehold,I am getting the data,how to receive in the controller and how to pass thru ajax call.thanks